# Calculated column in where-clause - performance

Tags: mysql, performance

Since you can't use a calculated column in a where-clause in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT a,b,c,(a*b+c) AS d FROM table
WHERE d > n
ORDER by d
```

you have to use

```
SELECT a,b,c,(a*b+c) AS d FROM table
WHERE (a*b+c) > n
ORDER by d
```

Is the calculation (in that example "(a*b+c)" executed once per row or twice? Is there a way to make it faster? I find it strange it's possible to ORDER on the column but not to have a WHERE-clause.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use HAVING to filter on a computed column:

```
SELECT a,b,c,(a*b+c) AS d, n FROM table
HAVING d > n
ORDER by d
```

Note that you need to include `n` in the SELECT clause for this to work.

Comment: that's great thanks! Is it performance-wise better / equal / worse than repeating the formula in a WHERE-clause? The readability is better of course :)

Comment: It's possible that the mysql optimizer is able to detect that the WHERE and SELECT formulas are the same, and not calculate it twice. But given mysql's track record, I doubt it. Benchmark it and see.

Comment: FYI: It appears that this solution only works for MySQL, and nor SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM 
(SELECT a,b,c,(a*b+c) AS d) AS tmp
WHERE d > n
ORDER BY d
```

But I am not sure what performance implications it could have.

Comment: `n` comes from the query in the initial question, I guess the poster meant by `n` some value.  If not, the subquery should be replaced with `(SELECT a,b,c,(a*b+c) AS d,n) AS tmp`