# usage of calculated field in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, yii2

Thanks for advance if some one help me.

Here is the query to filter some customer on different params.
At the last filter i need to filter customers against there balances which is calculative field in my query, when i am trying to use calculative field in where clause it shows me error of unknown fields, what should i do?

```
$sql = <<<SQL

        SELECT c.*, t.name as town_name, r.name as region_name, IFNULL((
            select sum(p.remaining) 
            from payments p
            left join sales s
            on s.payment_id = p.id
            where s.customer_id = c.id and s.status = 1
        ), 0) as credit_sales, 
        (
            IFNULL((
                SELECT sum(cl.amount)
                FROM customer_ledgers cl
                WHERE cl.customer_id = c.id and cl.status = 1 and cl.type = 1
            ), 0) 
            -
            IFNULL((
                SELECT sum(amount)
                FROM customer_ledgers
                WHERE customer_id = c.id and status=1 and type = 2
            ), 0)
        ) as balancex, (
          IFNULL( (
            SELECT `amount`
            FROM `customer_ledgers`
            WHERE customer_id = c.id and status = 1
            ORDER BY `date` DESC 
            LIMIT 1
          ), 0)
        ) as last_amount




        from customers c
        left join regions r
        on r.id = c.region_id
        left join towns t
        on  t.id = c.town_id
```

**SQL**

```
    # we need where?
    $sql .= 'WHERE c.status = 1';
    if (isset($params['CustomerSearch'])) {
        $sql .= " and ";
    }

    # add where statements to the query

    if (isset($params['CustomerSearch'])) {
            $isname     = isset($params['CustomerSearch']['name']);
            $istown     = isset($params['CustomerSearch']['region_name']);
            $isregion   = isset($params['CustomerSearch']['town_name']);
            $isbalance   = isset($params['CustomerSearch']['balancex']);

        if (isset($params['CustomerSearch']['name'])) {
            $this->name = trim($params['CustomerSearch']['name']);
            $sql .= " c.name like '%{$this->name}%'";
        }

        if (isset($params['CustomerSearch']['region_name']) && $params['CustomerSearch']['region_name'] !== '') {
            $this->region_name = trim($params['CustomerSearch']['region_name']);

            if ($isname) {
                $sql .= " and ";
            }
            $sql .= " r.id=" . $params['CustomerSearch']['region_name'];
        }

        if (isset($params['CustomerSearch']['town_name']) && $params['CustomerSearch']['town_name'] !== '') {
               $this->town_name = trim($params['CustomerSearch']['town_name']);

               if ($isname || $isregion) {
                   $sql .= " AND t.id = {$this->town_name}";
               }
           } 

        if (isset($params['CustomerSearch']['balancex']) && $params['CustomerSearch']['balancex'] !== '') {
               $this->balancex = trim($params['CustomerSearch']['balancex']);

               if ($isbalance) {
                   $sql .= " AND balancex > {$isbalance}";
               }
           }   
    }

    # town where clause.




    $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();


    return $result;
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [QueryBuilder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder) instead of raw sql, I think the result is much more cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use calculated fields in WHERE clause. You need to use HAVING clause.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16068737/4338862.

Comment: I`ll try this. Thank You.